# Invoking a method with return from non related component using RXJS or any other option

Tags: angular

Want to invoke Is Valid from component1.ts and check for the return value and do another logic based on the return value .
I have two component

```
1. Component1.ts
2. Component2.ts

// This is the method in component 2
Component2.ts has a method
Is Valid(): Boolean
{
return true;
}
```

Needs to invoke the method and return the value

Comment: You can use a Service for this.

Comment: I tried using it but dont know how to invoke a method with return type. CAn you provide a small snipet

Comment: Have you tried using subject behaviour for this? Try this https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

Comment: Yah tried those but no luck

Comment: Do these components have a parent-child relationship or not?

Comment: they are independent no relationship

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is [component communication](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-component-communication-81e5e02c6cbehttps://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-component-communication-81e5e02c6cbe).
Since your components are independent, using a service is a valid way to do this.

See [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yitcwx). It does pretty much what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsValidService {

  private isValid: boolean = false;


  constructor() { }

  get getIsValid(): boolean {
    return this.isValid;
  }

  set setIsValid(newVal: boolean) {
    this.isValid = newVal;
  }
}
```

Then from Component1 you can call the getter to get the value:

```
export class Component1{
  isValidFromComponent2 : boolean;
  constructor(private isValidService: IsValidService) { }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.isValidFromComponent2 = this.isValidService.getIsValid;
  }
}
```

From component2 you can set the value:

```
export class Component2{
  constructor(private isValidService: IsValidService) { }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.isValidService.setIsValid = false; //you can add logic here
  }
}
```